# Set height of p-element as percentage of containing div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to set the height of a `<p></p>` tag. Many suggest setting line-height or margin, but this won't suffice, as I want the p-tag to be as a percentage of the containig div. Actually, I want to vertically distribute the p-tags across the height. If I get them all to the same size, I can do this with `vertical-align` and `display: table` and `display: table-cell`

```
<div>
 <p>foo<p>
 <p>bar<p>
</div>
```

I know the number of `<p></p>` tags.

Comment: can you visually show what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p height="int%">lala </p>
```

that will set the height of the line of text as a percentage of the containg div I believe if not `<div height="int%" > <p> lalal </p> </div>` Then set the padding to work.
Will work. If you want the font to be stretched then I think you will need a new font.

Answer (score 0):

Width and height are supposed to be used with div only. Just change your

to  You may also need to set a min-height depending the surrounding mark-up, CSS.